# Facebook oEmbed requires app in live mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Cannot use a test Facebook app with oEmbed, it will return

```
   "error": {
      "message": "(#901) This endpoint requires app to be in live mode.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 901,
      "fbtrace_id": ""
   }
```

In a production app in Live mode you cannot have any unapproved roles as it won't get an access token.

What value is there in a test app? Since it cannot be used with oEmbed.

How to get an app approved by Facebook when you cannot have it it dev mode (since cannot also use it with oEmbed) and cannot have any unapproved roles in live mode? It seems stuck between rock & hard place.

Comment: Why can’t you have it in dev mode? What does oEmbed have to do with review in the first place?

Comment: _“In a production app in Live mode you cannot have any unapproved roles as it won't get an access token”_ - first of all, you mean _permissions_ here, not roles, and secondly, yes, you can have unapproved permissions and have the app in live mode - as long as you are not _asking_ users for those not yet approved permissions.